# method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount" - What happens when you call this method with an address that doesn't exist?

Tags: fork, ethereum, impersonation, hardhat

```js
async function impersonateAccount(acctAddress) {
  await hre.network.provider.request({
    method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
    params: [acctAddress],
  });
  return await ethers.getSigner(acctAddress);
}
```

When forking the blockchain locally on Hardhat, the function above allows developers to impersonate the address passed as argument to it.
So you can create transactions as if you're the owner of the account.

What happens when forking the mainnet, and you pass an address that does not exist on the mainnet as an argument?

Would it throw an error?
Does it create the account for you locally and give you access?

Answer (score 1):

It will create the account locally with a balance of 0 ETH.

I tried this with the Ropsten address `0xFD391b604E9456c0Ec4aC13Cc881FbAF68868eB2`, which currently has 210 testnet ETH and does not exist on the mainnet.

With your code example it will return a valid signer, and if you check the balance of the signer's address it will have 0 ETH.